# How do add text lines above a pivot table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do is to overwrite a data sheet and create a pivot table using the data in that sheet. The desired results look like this:

[image]

From left to right the columns represent the week, the cumulative sum av number of vaccinations, and the cumulative sum of the ratio of vaccinated people. Above the pivot there is a list allowing us to filter the results according to municipality.

I have managed to generate (via AI tools) an code snippet which "almost" recreates my desired results. It doesn't take the cumulative sums, but I might fix that by manipulating the underlying data in R. The difficulty lies in generating the two text lines above the pivot table.

This is my source data:

```
structure(list(region = c("10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10"), region_namn = c("Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", "Blekinge län", 
"Blekinge län"), kommun = c("1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", 
"1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", 
"1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", "1060", 
"1060", "1060", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", 
"1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", 
"1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", "1080", 
"1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", 
"1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", 
"1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1081", "1082", "1082", 
"1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", 
"1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", 
"1082", "1082", "1082", "1082", "1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", 
"1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", 
"1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", "1083", 
"1083", "1083"), kommun_namn = c("Olofström", "Olofström", 
"Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", 
"Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", 
"Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", 
"Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", "Olofström", 
"Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", 
"Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", 
"Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", 
"Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", 
"Karlskrona", "Karlskrona", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", 
"Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", 
"Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", 
"Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", "Ronneby", 
"Ronneby", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", 
"Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", 
"Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", 
"Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", 
"Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Karlshamn", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", 
"Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", 
"Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", 
"Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", 
"Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg", "Sölvesborg"
), week = c("2023-09", "2023-10", "2023-11", "2023-12", "2023-13", 
"2023-14", "2023-15", "2023-16", "2023-17", "2023-18", "2023-19", 
"2023-20", "2023-21", "2023-22", "2023-23", "2023-24", "2023-25", 
"2023-26", "2023-27", "2023-28", "2023-29", "2023-30", "2023-09", 
"2023-10", "2023-11", "2023-12", "2023-13", "2023-14", "2023-15", 
"2023-16", "2023-17", "2023-18", "2023-19", "2023-20", "2023-21", 
"2023-22", "2023-23", "2023-24", "2023-25", "2023-26", "2023-27", 
"2023-28", "2023-29", "2023-30", "2023-09", "2023-10", "2023-11", 
"2023-12", "2023-13", "2023-14", "2023-15", "2023-16", "2023-17", 
"2023-18", "2023-19", "2023-20", "2023-21", "2023-22", "2023-23", 
"2023-24", "2023-25", "2023-26", "2023-27", "2023-28", "2023-29", 
"2023-30", "2023-09", "2023-10", "2023-11", "2023-12", "2023-13", 
"2023-14", "2023-15", "2023-16", "2023-17", "2023-18", "2023-19", 
"2023-20", "2023-21", "2023-22", "2023-23", "2023-24", "2023-25", 
"2023-26", "2023-27", "2023-28", "2023-29", "2023-30", "2023-09", 
"2023-10", "2023-11", "2023-12", "2023-13", "2023-14", "2023-15", 
"2023-16", "2023-17", "2023-18", "2023-19", "2023-20", "2023-21", 
"2023-22", "2023-23", "2023-24", "2023-25", "2023-26", "2023-27", 
"2023-28", "2023-29", "2023-30"), pop = c(10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 
10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 
10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 
10738L, 10738L, 10738L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 
53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 
53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 53220L, 
53220L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 
22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 
22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 22943L, 25932L, 
25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 
25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 
25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 25932L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 
14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 
14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 14278L, 
14278L, 14278L, 14278L), antal = c(145, 48, 81, 68, 65, 45, 93, 
88, 393, 56, 83, 15, 81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 764, 772, 
649, 464, 435, 225, 411, 865, 798, 368, 397, 186, 161, 59, 14, 
76, 23, 31, 0, 37, 0, 18, 167, 208, 282, 218, 217, 171, 170, 
338, 503, 214, 229, 87, 60, 34, 14, 49, 17, 7, 0, 8, 5, 6, 147, 
275, 294, 254, 252, 208, 303, 248, 546, 144, 192, 63, 39, 38, 
16, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 46, 138, 77, 158, 119, 90, 42, 247, 
281, 66, 44, 23, 28, 22, 0, 43, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 10), ratio = c(0.0135034457068355, 
0.00447010616502142, 0.00754330415347365, 0.00633265040044701, 
0.00605326876513317, 0.00419072452970758, 0.008660830694729, 
0.0081951946358726, 0.0365989942261129, 0.00521512385919166, 
0.0077295585770162, 0.00139690817656919, 0.00754330415347365, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0143555054490793, 0.0145058248778655, 
0.0121946636602781, 0.0087185268695979, 0.00817361894024803, 
0.00422773393461105, 0.00772266065388952, 0.0162532882375047, 
0.0149943630214205, 0.00691469372416385, 0.00745960165351372, 
0.00349492671927847, 0.00302517850432168, 0.00110860578729801, 
0.000263059000375799, 0.00142803457346862, 0.000432168357760241, 
0.000582487786546411, 0, 0.000695227358136039, 0, 0.000338218714768884, 
0.00727890859957285, 0.00906594604018655, 0.0122913306890991, 
0.00950180883058013, 0.00945822255154078, 0.00745325371573029, 
0.00740966743669093, 0.0147321623153031, 0.0219238983567973, 
0.0093274637144227, 0.00998125790001308, 0.00379200627642418, 
0.0026151767423615, 0.00148193348733819, 0.000610207906551018, 
0.00213572767292856, 0.000740966743669093, 0.000305103953275509, 
0, 0.000348690232314867, 0.000217931395196792, 0.00026151767423615, 
0.00566867191115224, 0.0106046583371896, 0.0113373438223045, 
0.00979484806416782, 0.00971772327626099, 0.00802097794231066, 
0.0116844053678852, 0.00956347370044732, 0.0210550670985655, 
0.00555298472929199, 0.00740397963905599, 0.00242943081906525, 
0.00150393336418325, 0.00146537097022983, 0.000616998303254666, 
0.000192811969767083, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000308499151627333, 0.00322173973945931, 
0.00966521921837792, 0.00539291217257319, 0.0110659756268385, 
0.00833450063034038, 0.00630340383807256, 0.00294158845776719, 
0.017299341644488, 0.019680627538871, 0.00462249614791988, 0.00308166409861325, 
0.00161086986972965, 0.0019610589718448, 0.00154083204930663, 
0, 0.00301162627819022, 0, 0.00112060512676845, 0, 0, 0, 0.000700378204230284
)), row.names = c(NA, -110L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

This is the VBA macro I've been using this far:

```
Sub UpdatePivotTableRange()
    Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartPoint As Range
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim NewRange As String
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim DownCell As Long
    Dim PTCache As PivotCache
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim PField As PivotField
    Dim KommunRange As Range ' Add a variable to hold the range for 'kommun' filter

    ' Set Source Worksheet
    Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data veckostatistik aktiv dos")
    
    ' Defining Starting Point & Dynamic Range
    Data_Sheet.Activate
    Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("A1")
    LastCol = StartPoint.End(xlToRight).Column
    DownCell = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
    Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range(StartPoint, Data_Sheet.Cells(DownCell, LastCol))
    NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    ' Create a PivotCache based on the new data range
    Set PTCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, NewRange)

    ' Delete the old PivotSheet and create a new one
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Veckostatistik påfyllnad").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Veckostatistik påfyllnad"

    ' Set Destination Worksheet
    Set Pivot_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Veckostatistik påfyllnad")
    

    ' Create the PivotTable in the new sheet, using the PivotCache
    Set PT = Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables.Add(PTCache, Pivot_Sheet.Range("A1"), "PivotTable1")

    ' Set up the PivotTable fields
    With PT
        .PivotFields("week").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("week").Position = 1

        ' Check if the data field exists before setting the .Function property
        If FieldExists("antal", PT) Then
            Set PField = .PivotFields("antal")
            PField.Orientation = xlDataField
            PField.Function = xlSum
            PField.Position = 1
            PField.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        End If
        
        ' Check if the data field exists before setting the .Function property
        If FieldExists("ratio", PT) Then
            Set PField = .PivotFields("ratio")
            PField.Orientation = xlDataField
            PField.Function = xlSum
            PField.Position = 2
            PField.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        End If
        
        ' Check if the data field exists before setting the .Function property
        If FieldExists("andel", PT) Then
            Set PField = .PivotFields("andel")
            PField.Orientation = xlDataField
            PField.Function = xlSum
            PField.Position = 3
            PField.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        End If

        .PivotFields("kommun").Orientation = xlPageField
        .PivotFields("kommun").Position = 1
        .PivotFields("kommun").ClearAllFilters ' Clear existing filters

        ' Add the range for 'kommun' filter dynamically
        Dim CommArr() As Variant
        Dim UniqueComms() As Variant
        Dim i As Long
        
        CommArr = Data_Sheet.Range("A2:A" & DownCell).Value ' assuming 'kommun' data starts from A2
        UniqueComms = GetUniqueValues(CommArr)
        
        Dim FirstCell As Range
        Set FirstCell = Data_Sheet.Cells(1, 1)
        Dim LastCell As Range
        Set LastCell = Data_Sheet.Cells(UBound(UniqueComms) + 1, 1)
        Set KommunRange = Data_Sheet.Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
        
        ' Apply the Autofilter method to the 'kommun' field with the range
        KommunRange.AutoFilter field:=1

        ' Your existing code...
    End With
End Sub

' Your existing code...

Function FieldExists(fieldName As String, PT As PivotTable) As Boolean
    Dim field As PivotField
    On Error Resume Next
    Set field = PT.PivotFields(fieldName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    FieldExists = Not field Is Nothing
End Function

Function GetUniqueValues(arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i
    
    GetUniqueValues = dict.keys
End Function
```

And this is the rcode i use in order to add the data and activate the macro:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(RDCOMClient)
    
wb <- loadWorkbook(filepath)

# Delete the old sheet
removeWorksheet(wb, "Data veckostatistik aktiv dos")

# Add a new worksheet with the same name
addWorksheet(wb, "Data veckostatistik aktiv dos")

# Write the new data to the new sheet
# Assuming 'test' is your new data
writeData(wb, "Data veckostatistik aktiv dos", test)

# Save the workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, filepath, overwrite = TRUE)


 # Open a specific workbook in Excel:
   xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
   xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(copied_file)

   # This line of code is only necessary if you want to see your spreadsheet getting updated:
   xlApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE 

   # Run the macro called "UpdatePivotTableRange":
   xlApp$Run("UpdatePivotTableRange")

   # Close the workbook and quit the app:
   xlWbk$Close(FALSE)
   xlApp$Quit()

   # Release resources:
   rm(xlWbk, xlApp)
   gc()
```

In addition I've been given this suggestion by phind. This is after the Pivot_sheet has been modified to start at A4 instead of A1. When I try this, however, I get weird error messages. I get told that there's already data in my fields and get queried if I want to overwrite it. When i press "yes", the file closes and when I open it again, the two text rows on top as been deleted...

```
Pivot_Sheet.Range("A1").Value = "Vaccinerade, totalt, med minst 3 doser varav senaste dos efter 2023-03-01 per vecka (kumulativt) och kommun utifrån den vaccinerades folkbokföringsadress."
Pivot_Sheet.Range("A2").Value = "Antal och andel av befolkningen i länet födda 2004 eller tidigare"
```

I figure this is probably something as pasting the code snippet in the correct place, but these AI tools have got me running in circles. Apologies for my lack of understanding of VBA code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there another reference apart from  Set PT = Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables.Add(PTCache, Pivot_Sheet.Range("A1"), "PivotTable1")? I guess there is "Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("A1")" but this seems to refer to the sheet with the source data, and I don't really see why that reference would need to be changed.....

Comment: You are right, i hadn't looked at it carefully enough. I'll delete my comment.